# Health check for DB using SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

Can you please help me with a script inorder to do the health check of the DB using SQL server 2008.

Thanks.

Comment: Check http://www.sqlservercentral.com/Forums/Topic407487-5-1.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use following command :

```
dbcc checkdb
```

Answer (score 0):

There's no silver bullet or golden rule here. First you ill need to define what's a health DB. Second what do you need to check? Indexes, deadlocks, FKs, etc. Third what do you do to keep the DB healthy, reindex, clear log, check DB growth? Last, are you doing backups? Do you have disaster recovery plan? Ill that backup restore the DB for a healthy state? How much ill be lost?

As you see you make a question over a extensive topics. I suggest you head for SQL Server Central a great source for DBAs and hit the books. You ill find a lot of checkdb scripts but you ill see you need more than a plan script. You ill need to know what to do if that script prints a error message.